# Draw image in function

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-1.2

I want an image to be drawn when the space key is pressed. This is my code:

```
void drawImage()
{
   rect.x = 100;
   rect.y = 100;

   SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load("image.png");
   SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, screen, &rect);
}
```

Here is it called:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
{
    if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
    {
        gameRunning = false;
    }
    if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE)
        {
            drawImage();
        }
    }

}
```

The image isn't drawn when I press the space key. What is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you're missing to flip the surfaces

Comment: @Photon oops that was it. But when I press space the image appears but when I release space it disappears. How do I solve this then?

Comment: @WilhelmMichaelsen: SDL is immediate drawing, not a retained scene graph.  If you want the image to show up in future frames, you have to render it again in future frames (save it in memory, don't access the file every time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flip](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Flip) the screen buffers (SDL_Surfaces).

Answer (score 1):

After your line

```
SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, screen, &rect);
```

Add

```
SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Does the function draws, in the main loop without the space pressing thing?

```
bool draw = false;

while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
{
    if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
    {
        gameRunning = false;
    }
    if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE)
        {
           draw = true;
        }
    }

}


int main()
{  
  if(draw){ 
    drawImage();
  }
    //DO SOME ERROR CHECKING

}
```

Comment: his code does not have a fill/clear screen function, so this is not the case.